# Is it possible to setup SSL for AWS public DNS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm newbee with AWS. I have EC2 instance (windows server + IIS). Does it possible to assign SSL certificate to AWS public DNS (xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xx.eu-central-2.compute.amazonaws.com) ? Can I do that without load balancer ? (OpenSSL for example)
Tried to find  something, but all what I've found
 - use custom domain
 - let's encrypt blocks aws public hosts

I need https for testing purposes and don't want to break brain with DNS changes on hosting.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the certificate is tied to the domain name it would be better to use either your dns provider and create a cname record for the server you are testing with and generate a cert based on that cname or forward your domain to route53 ( after you set it up ) and manage domain mapping within aws with aws route 53 (dns server)